# visual studio solution explorer - the idea of filters

Tags: visual-studio, filter, directory, solution-explorer

As I have understood you can not display the actual folder tree of the project, the only way to look at your project's files is via the solution explorer. The solution explorer does not show you the actual folder system, instead it shows filters.

I already have a well orginized folder tree which I want to look at while I work, to do that I have to duplicate every actual folder to a filter and add/delete/change them as I change the folders.

Why do I must use filters? Why would visual studio force you to use filters? What is the idea of them if I have to maintain them as I change the folder tree?